# Combining integer and string in array value

Tags: php, arrays, date, string-concatenation

Can someone please tell me where I messed up and/or how I can solve this?

***Working code (PHP):***

```
public $data = array(
    ....
    ....
    'copyright' => array(
         'es' => '2013 Mi Empresa',
         'en' => '2013 My Company',
     ),
    ....
    ....    
);
```

***Broken code:***

```
public $data = array(
    ....
    ....
    'copyright' => array(
       'es' => date('Y') . ' Mi Empresa',
       'en' => date('Y') . ' My Company',
     ),
    ....
    ....    
);
```

When I say broken, I mean that the resulting `<body>` is empty. I have also tried adding `(string)date('Y')` in place of `date('Y')`, to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: PHP has no problem concatenating integers and strings. It will always convert an integer to a string in this case. Can you `var_dump(date('Y') . ' Mi Empresa');` and see what the output is?

Comment: is this a class property declaration? no you can't do that, it needs to be setup in the constructor

Comment: @JonathanCrowe: I only have access to the source files. Can I do var_dump in the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't setup your properties like that:

```
class Test
{
    // this won't work
    public $data = array(
        'copyright' => array(
            'es' => date('Y') . ' Mi Empresa',
            'en' => date('Y') . ' My Company',
        ),
    );

    // even as simple as this
    public $date_now = date('Y-m-d');
}
```

Quoting the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> They (properties) are defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or private, followed by a normal variable declaration. This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

It simply means PHP doesn't do such operations at compile-time; you cannot assign calculated values and functions to constants.

Set it up on the constructor:

```
class Test
{
    public $data = array(
        'copyright' => array(
            'es' => '',
            'en' => '' ,
        ),
    );

    public $date_today = '';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->data['copyright']['es'] = date('Y') . ' Mi Empresa';
        $this->data['copyright']['en'] = date('Y') . ' My Company';
        $this->date_today = date('Y-m-d');
    }
}

$test = new Test();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($test);
```

Sidenote: The problem in that no error issue thing is that most likely error reporting is turned OFF. (White screen of death).

Always turn it on in development stages:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```